# How to overwrite Windows Phone Suggestion Bar programmatically?

Tags: windows-phone-7, toolbar

Talking about **Suggestion Bar** as we can see [here](http://www.windowsphone.com/en-us/how-to/wp7/basics/copy-and-paste), I'd like to know if there's a way to show/hide this bar programmatically, and/or add/remove buttons in it programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

That's Context Menu you are referring to. Checking this link for how to use Contextmenu in your app

[WP7 ContextMenu in depth](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/WP7-ContextMenu-in-depth--Part1-key-concepts-and-API)